# Does hotspot connect directly to proxy or through the computer from the connection being shared?

Tags: windows-10, proxy, proxy-server, wireless-hotspot

Let's say I have connected my phone to the internet through the hotspot from my Laptop. In order to access the internet, i have to configure proxy in both laptop and android. Now on the server side would the traffic come from my laptop or it would be shown as different i.e coming from the android?

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, traffic would come from your laptop, however if browsing the web the phone would pass its own User Agent (Android) value in the request headers.